# Appending itterable columns into an empty frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have multiple folders, each contains multiple "tsv" files.
I need to append "TESS" columns of 16 different files into one empty dataframe, with corresponding index.
I have created an empty frame but with "full" index named `"all_methods"` - the index were made from all available variables within the seperated 16 files.
How do I save "TESS" columns values into each columns separately by order? for instance:
First print goes to "C1", second to "C2", third to "E1" and so on. Index must match, but I have already put isin index.
*Note, in case there is no match between the empty frame to the printed one, Nan is fine

```
os.chdir(r'....')
c4_add = pd.read_csv('c4symbols.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=[0])
c5_add = pd.read_csv('c5symbols.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=[0])
c6_add = pd.read_csv('c6symbols.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=[0])
c7_add = pd.read_csv('c7symbols.csv', index_col=[0], usecols=[0])
combined_symbols = c4_add.combine(c5_add, c6_add, c7_add)
combined_symbols = combined_symbols.index[1:-1]

all_methods = pd.DataFrame(index=combined_symbols, columns = ['C1','C2','E1','E2','M1','M2','M3','M4',
                                'Q1','Q2','Q3','T1','T2','T3','X1','X2'])

for root,dirs, files in os.walk(r'.....'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tsv") and file.__contains__('report_for_na'):
            with open(os.path.join(root,file), 'r') as auto:
                df = pd.read_table(auto, sep='\t')
                if len(df.T) == 12:
                    df.set_index('NAME', inplace = True)
                    df = df[['TESS']]
                    df = df[df.index.isin(all_methods.index)]
                    for i in df['TESS']:
                       for a in all_methods:
                        d = pd.DataFrame({a:i}, index = all_methods.index)
                        print(d) -- > I did something wrong in the loop ..
```

Comment: Curious, why `open` each .tsv file and not read directly into `read_table`?

Comment: Acually possible.. I combined some old code I wrote and this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC - You appear to need a horizontal merge by index. Therefore, consider using a defined method to import each .tsv and run needed data frame operations. Then call method in a list comprehension to build a list of data frames. And instead of iterating across all files add an intermediary loop across all directories to properly reference file in absolute name.

Afterwards, run horizontal merge with [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (adjusting `axis` default value to `axis=1`). Finally, run [**`DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join `all_methods` master data frame on matching index. Note: below is untested so may require adjustments on your end.

```py
def get_tsv_data(f): 
    # DIRECT READ OF TEXT FILE
    raw = pd.read_table(f, sep='\t')

    if len(df.T) == 12:
        # SET INDEX AND KEEP ONLY TESS COLUMN
        df = raw.set_index("NAME").reindex(["TESS"], axis=1)
    else:
        df = None     

    return df

# BUILD LIST OF DATA FRAMES
tsv_frames = [
               get_tsv_data(os.path.join(root, dir, file)) 
               for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r".....")
               for dir in dirs
               for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir))
               if file.endswith(".tsv") and file.__contains__('report_for_na')
             ]

# HORIZONTAL MERGE
tsv_df = pd.concat(tsv_frames, axis=1)

# JOIN TO MASTER DATA FRAME AND RENAME COLUMNS
new_cols = ['C1','C2','E1','E2','M1','M2','M3','M4',
            'Q1','Q2','Q3','T1','T2','T3','X1','X2']

all_methods = all_methods.join(tsv_df).set_axis(new_cols, axis=1)
```